# Why I can't use argument for require function as a variable

Tags: node.js

When I am trying to load module via require, I can not do it by passing there a variable, I can only hardcode it there.

So, for example this code works:

```
const module = require('module')
```

But following code does not:

```
const moduleName = 'module'
const module = require(moduleName)
```

That's kinda weird, does anyone know why so?

Comment: I need to do this for very specific reason

Comment: so... presumably, if it's not working, you're getting some kind of error message or behavior that helps you determine that it isn't working.

Comment: @KevinB I've just found a reason, it happens because require loads module before the runtime of the actual code, so all the variables don't exist at that moment.

Comment: Are you using a bundler like webPack or something like that.  Those require static strings for `require()` so they can analyze dependencies without actually running your code.

Comment: requiring module in node js via a string variable is quite possible.

Comment: @ambianBeing No, it's not

Comment: @GuseynIsmayylov As @jfriend00 nentioned as well. I tested exactly as in your question at `node v10.16.3`. It works just fine.

Comment: BTW, if you showed us your actual code in the original question, we could have helped you with a solution to your packaging issue.  I never understand why people feel the need to make up code to ask a generic question rather than show us their ACTUAL code.  We can help so much more effectively when we see the real code.  Please consider doing that next time.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not a packaging issue, thanks. I decided to have a workaround, which is pointless to show here as it has nothing with the problem.

Comment: It's not a packaging issue, yet you accepted an answer that says its a packaging issue?  Huh?  This doesn't sound like you're using the site properly here or it is actually packaging related.  I showed you in my answer that using variables with `require()` works just fine when not doing static packaging or using some other preprocessing tool

Comment: yeah, sorry, it is a packaging issue, thanks

Comment: OK.  Good, glad to clear that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normal node.js Javascript (that does not use a packager or some other preprocessing build tool) will work just fine with variables sent to `require()` so this is not a generic issue with `require()` in node.js.

But, if you are using a bundler like webPack or some preprocessing build tool like that then those typically require static strings for `require()` so they can analyze dependencies without actually running your code.

Oh, by the way using `const module` as the variable name is a bad idea since `module` is already defined in your scope by node.js and that name would even cause an error if you actually tried to run that code.

As an example, this code runs just fine in node.js:

```
const mod = 'fs';
const fs = require(mod);

let data = fs.readFileSync("./file1.txt");
console.log(data);
```

Comment: ```
Normal node.js Javascript that does not use a packager will work just fine with variables sent to require().
```

No it will not. I just want to get rid of big `switch` statement in my code.

Comment: @GuseynIsmayylov -  Please show us your ACTUAL code.  And, please state whether you're using any sort of packager or bundler.  I've used variables with `require()` before and it works just fine if you don't have something else going on in your build process that messes it up.

Comment: @GuseynIsmayylov - BTW, using `const module` as the variable name is a bad idea since `module` is already defined within the scope of a module and is important to be able to use as its original name.

Comment: @GuseynIsmayylov - I just tested the sample code I have in my  answer and it works just fine with node v10.16.0.  So, it's not a generic issue with using variables.

Answer (score 0):

Based on how the packager works, this isn't really possible with require.
Packaging happens once before runtime so those variables don't have values yet.